# google sheets highlight number of columns between 2 dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I fill in (highlight) the cells between to 'From' and 'To' in the calendar below?

At the moment with conditional formatting I can do the From and To columns individually but thats not what I need. If the date difference is 5 days then 5 consecutive cells need to be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: What formula did you use to fill 08 16, 08 20, 08 18 and 08 20?

Comment: The From and To dates have been manually entered using the UK date format.

Comment: I mean what formula did you use to place those white and black circles, or was it done by hand?

Comment: I used =IF($E7=U$3,"⚪",IF($F7=U$3,"⚫","")) but these only highlight the individually cells.

Comment: =IF($E7=U$3,"⚪",IF($F7=U$3,"⚫",IF(AND(U$3>$E7,U$3<$F7),"Whatever sign you need","")))

Comment: I have a conditional format rule =AND($F7=G$3,$B7=$B$30), which adds a background colour to the cell. How do I adjust this so all the cells in the date range (From and To) have this background colour applied to? Thanks

Comment: =AND((cell with day>=date from),(cell with day<=day to))

Comment: Unfortunately, the above didn't work. It highlights all the cells.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=isbetween(G$3,$E7,$F7)
```

- *Adjust the ranges as per your sheet*

[image]

Comment: =isbetween(G$3,$E7,$F7) changes the background colour all cells ignoring the colour selected in the status column. E.g. If ONHOLD is selected then those cells in date range should be orange. If READY then green etc.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get this sorted?

Comment: Its best if you could post a fresh question outlining these selective-color-coding requirements & hopefully someone on this forum will offer a tailored solution. Cool